# Splitting a string to the nth delimiter

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to split a string, keep the delimiters and save to a new string based on the Nth delimiter. For example.

```
String s = "HELLO-WORLD-GREAT-DAY"
```

I would like to store `HELLO-WORLD-GREAT` and chop off the `-DAY`.

I can capture the individual elements using `split[x]` but I cant seem to figure out the best way to assert this to a new `string` to be used later on.

Any idea's folks?

I have tried to use split last and first etc.

I need to be able to capture first three elements of the input string

Comment: At first glance the answers seem to target your example (split at last occurence).  Is this what the question is about?  Your subject seems to suggest otherwise (e.g. the function should take the position and e.g. also work to create `HELLO-WORLD` / `GREAT-DAY` (split at 2nd occurence))

Answer (score 1):

Split and combine:

```
public String removeLast(String input) {
    //Split your input
    String[] parts = input.split("-");

    //Combine to a new string, leaving out the last one
    String output = parts[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
        output += "-" + parts[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public String removeLast(String target, String delimiter) {
    int pos = target.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
    return pos == -1 ? target : target.substring(0, pos);
}
```

You would call the method like this:

```
String result = removeLast("HELLO-WORLD-GREAT-DAY", "-");
```

Comment: Hey, thank you all for replying so quickly, this was the first time ive used this and i didnt expect such a quick response. 

So I am trying to do it in groovy and its throwing an error when i use this approach. Just returns null

Comment: This code is written in pure Java, so you will have to adjust it for working in Groovy. As far as I'm concerned, you should be able to invoke the Java library methods that are used in this solution from Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Two easy ways I can think of:

```
String hw = "HELLO-WORLD-GREAT-DAY"

def result = hw - hw.substring(hw.lastIndexOf('-'))
```

And `String.join` with `split`'s result:

```
def result = String.join('-', hw.split('-')[0..-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

With groovy you can do

```
​"HELLO-WORLD-GREAT-DAY".split('-')[0..-2].join('-')​​​​
```